# Uninstall Visual Studio 2015 Community - Uninstall button disabled?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, uninstallation

Trying to remove Visual Studio 2015 Community edition (as I am now using 2017) on a Windows 10 desktop computer.

However, when I go the "Apps & Features" the Uninstall button is disabled!

[image: Uninstall button disabled]

How do you remove VS 2015 Community when this happens without clobbering 2017?

Unfortunately, I inherited this workstation and no one seems to know where the original install disks (if any) are!  I also found Visual Studio 2010 and 2013 exist on this workstation.  I suspect VS 2015 was simply downloaded and installed; hence no original disks per se.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the quick replies -- shortly after I posted, I did manage to find the following (in case anyone else runs into this "feature"):

**Uninstalling VS 2010**

The following blog lead me to an uninstaller for VS2010:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2010/08/23/visual-studio-2010-uninstall-utility/

The Uninstall archive (for VS2010) is available at:
https://aka.ms/vs2010uninstall

I then ran the command (as per the instructions):

```
VS2010_Uninstall-RTM.ENU.exe /full
```

Worked without any issues.

**Uninstalling VS2013 and VS2015:**

Download the uninstaller from:
https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller

Simply run the installer as per the directions given -- **BUT BE PATIENT** -- It took almost an hour to remove all the components (this may be because my particular system had so many earlier versions installed).

Once the above was done, I was then able to open the control panel and use the "Change" option.   A dialog then opens that includes an "Uninstall" button that was enabled.

I then ran the Visual Studio Installer (2017) and choose Update to make sure everything was up-to-date.

Rebooted -- so far, everything is working and the system dropped a few hundred stale MSIs!

Answer (score 9):

Press the Modify and it will give uninstall option.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use the software that comes with it if its a new install called [visual studio installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6V8O.png). Alos have you tried the old uninstall in windows? You can access it via "Run => Control Panel => Programs => Programs and Features"?

Comment: Also what about the modify button? This normally generally processes through the same steps.

Answer (score 0):

At the end and after trying a lot of different things trying to fix my situation, I found out how to solve it.

I went into the VS2017 Installer and then I hit to modify the installation. I just clicked in the box for "asp.net and web development" and then hit again, and it looks like something needed to be downloaded and installed (among the options there was one of IIS Express and it was pre-selected).

After all the process finished, I was able to reopen the solution and the project was automatically loaded as before.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22808486)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I wanted to add as a comment in the answer from the post owner but because of my reputation it was not possible.

Comment: If you don't have sufficient reputation to post comments, then don't abuse answers in an attempt to circumvent that. Answers are for answers to the question only. Not for comments, not for follow-up questions nor for "I'm having this problem too" type comments.

Comment: Ok, I know now. But at the end I thing I could give a good feedback for some other people. I thought it was not going to be productive to create a question to a related problem. I can move it.